# How to compare strings in C for a condition

Tags: c, string

I'm having trouble comparing two strings in C to see if they are equal.

```
switch(i) {
case 1:
  printf("Got in case 1.  TextA=%s    word=%s \n",TextA,word);
  if(TextA == word) {       
    SubTypeOption = 1;
    printf("SubTypeOptioon = %d",SubTypeOption);
  }
```

On my output, i get "Got in case 1.  TextA=SupTypeA    word=SupTypeA 
                     SubTypeOption = 0"  //So it wasn't changed somehow

Answer (score 6):

The `==` operator compares *pointers*. It succeeds only when the two `char*` point to the same address in memory. Comparing strings' *content* in C requires a call of [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) or [`strncmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html):

```
if (strcmp(TextA, word) == 0) {
    // Strings are identical
}
```

Note the comparison to zero: it is required because `strcmp` functions compare strings *lexicographically*, returning zero when the strings are equal. You need to include `<strings.h>` in order to use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 5):

use `strcmp`

not the '==' operator

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings using the `==` symbol, because you are comparing whether they are placed in the same memory location or not. `TextA` and `word` are pointers to the first character of each c-string.

Used `strcmp()` or `strlcmp()` functions to compare strings. They'll return 0 if the two strings are equal

```
#define STREQ(a,b) (strcmp((a),(b))==0)
if (STREQ(TextA, word)){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare the contents of strings (or any other array type) with the standard relational operators like `==`, `<`, `>`, etc.  You will need to use the `strcmp` library function instead:

```
#include <string.h>
...
if (strcmp(TextA, word) == 0)
{
  // strings are equal
}
```

`strcmp` will return an integer value < 0 if `TextA` is lexicographically less than `word`, 0 if they are lexicographically equal, and > 0 if `TextA` is lexicographically greater than `word`.

Note that, in the C locale, this means strings will be ordered "ASCIIbetically"; that is, any string beginning with `'a'` will come after a string beginning with `'Z'`, since the ASCII code for `'a'` is greater than `'Z'`.

So why can't you use `==` for comparing strings?

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

This means that, in the condition `TextA == word`, both of the expressions `TextA` and `word` are being converted to pointer values; instead of comparing the contents of the two arrays, we're comparing their addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - use [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) - that is the function that you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(i) {
case 1:
  printf("Got in case 1.  TextA=%s    word=%s \n",TextA,word);
  if(strcmp(TextA,word)==0) {       //something like that
    SubTypeOption = 1;
    printf("SubTypeOptioon = %d",SubTypeOption);
  }
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/