# Skip Directory on Listing in GNU C

Tags: c

First of all, I'm a complete novice at programming, especially in C.  The example I'm going to show is code I've snagged from this site and 
kicked until it didn't quite do what I wanted. :)

Second, I'm using a dual-core Celeron with Linux Mint and the GNU C Compiler.

What I want to do is list the subdirectories within a directory, skipping the parent directory if any.  Unfortunately, the code I have 
doesn't work.  I tried strcpy and strncpy, but I couldn't figure out how to use them and I just screwed up the code so that I got a 
"segmentation fault" when I tried to run the program.

Here's the code:

```
/*
 * This program displays the names of all files in the current directory.
 */

#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR           *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char dirname[255];
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR) 
            {
                strncpy(dirname, dir->d_name, 254);
                dirname[254] = '\0';
                if (dirname != "..") /* I want to skip this, but it doesn't work */
                {
                    printf ("%s\n", dirname);
                }
            }
        }


        closedir(d);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.  I'd especially be interested in links to sites that can offer tutorials that would help me with this 
little project, as I want a better understanding of what the heck I'm doing. :)

Comment: `if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR) { if (strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0) { printf("%s\n", dir->d_name); } }`

Comment: If you want to understand what you're doing, start from the beginning!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare strings in C for a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779112/how-to-compare-strings-in-c-for-a-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, to compare strings you need to use either `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

```
if (strcmp(dirname, "..") != 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah, so that's how to use it! :)  Makes perfect sense when shown, but the example in the tutorial I was using was doing something totally different, so I couldn't apply it.  Many thanks.